# How to use google find my face

Tags: android, google-plus, photo-gallery, face-recognition

I am trying to make a photo organization app in android in which i was planning on using facial recognition. Since Google+ already has a facial recognition mechanism in place i was wondering how can I integrate it with my app. Basically my app will pull photos from the users G+ account and display them in a customized and better organized layout. Is their anyway to extract the facial recognition output, as in the x-y coordinates of the face or anything else, using a query in the G+ API ? I have been scouring the net but was not able to find anything concrete on this.

Thanks
Ayush

P.S : This is my first question and I hope I was able to make myself clear enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe that is part of the G+ API.  If you really want to detect the outline of the face, look into some other API's that do such.

Here's a list of several face detection API's
http://blog.mashape.com/post/53379410412/list-of-40-face-detection-recognition-apis

If you're dead set on using G+ the photo's would probably have to already have the face tagged.  Then you'd have to rely on some sort of scrapping method to get that javascript code and decode/parse it.

You'd be better off using a face detection API.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast :)
I have used OpenCV and made a custom mechanism for the same but its accuracy is nowhere close to G+. Ill look into the scrapping model !

Comment: Google has a lot of machine power, and machine learning algorithms there in house.  I'd love it if they'd provide an API to utilize them.